# Pass context from router into controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I am writing some reusable code which would allow a resource to be nested under some other resource. The routing may look something like this:

```
resources :items do
  resources :shared_users
end

resources :things do
  resources :shared_users
end
```

The routing works great, but the problem occurs when I get into the controller. When I am inside the controller, I want to know which resource I am nested under. I can't necessarily just inspect the request path or parameters because this code is reusable, and I have no idea what resources it may be nested under.

What I would like is something like this:

```
resources :items do
  resources :shared_users, context: 'item'
end

resources :things do
  resources :shared_users, context: 'thing'
end
```

And then in the controller:

```
class SharedUsersController
  def index
    # Access context and react accordingly
  end
end
```

For example, the controller may want to load the `Item` or `Thing` class depending on the request (i.e. on a request to `/items/1/shared_users` the controller should be able to use the `Item` class to load resources).

How would I hand in this sort of context from the router to the controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it exactly as you did in your example code:

```
resources :items do
  resources :shared_users, context: 'item'
end
```

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match), any option that Rails does not recognise is passed on as a request parameter. In your controller you can simply do:

```
def index
  context = params[:context] # => 'item'
end
```

Comment: Ok, yeah that did work. I had tried that, but my tests were giving me "No route matches" errors. When I try it in the browser, however, it works fine. Now I gotta figure out why rspec doesn't like it...

Comment: Good point. I see the same error when running a controller spec, haven't found a workaround for that though.